# RangeChecks instrumentation code detected and out of range error access

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to reinitialize an array so that I can insert another values.

```
bReadBuffer[nBUFFERSIZE] ={ 0 } ;
```

1- How to remove the debugging exception?

```
#endif
{
   if(IsProcessorFeaturePresent(PF_FASTFAIL_AVAILABLE))
   {
      __fastfail(failure_code);//exception in this line
   }
```

Comment: What debugging exception are you talking about?

Comment: RangeChecks instrmentation code detected and out of range error access.

Comment: Please edit that into your post.

Comment: @blackbrandt I have edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `bReadBuffer[nBUFFERSIZE] = { 0 }` **does not do** what you think. It will try to set the value at index `nBUFFERSIZE` (which is **out of bound** - the reason of your range access error) to 0.

- You could use `std::fill_n` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) to reset you C style array.
- Or embed the array inside a struct so that you can use `= { 0 };` to initialize the whole structure with 0.

Or even better use **C++ types** like:

- `std::array` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or
- `std::vector` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

which will provide easier way to clear data.

So you remove the debugging exception by writing correct code. And you write correct code by reading books to learn how the C++ language works.